# Unable to export as .glTF, "mesh does not have morph targets"

Tags: export, shape-keys

I've been struggling with exporting this project as a .glTF for a few weeks now.

[image: A render of the animation.]

My goal is to have a .glTF that plays the animation of the character grinding on the rails.

I selected only what I needed, and set the GLB export settings to only export what's selected.

When I try to open the .glTF in Microsoft's 3D Viewer, it crashes before it can even open the file. I tried opening it in this [online glTF viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) to get a detailed description as to what's wrong with the file, and I get the following error:

```
Animation channel cannot target WEIGHTS when mesh does not have morph targets.
```

I've inferred that "Morph Targets” are synonymous with "Shape Keys". I converted everything into a mesh, made sure every object had at least one shape key, and even disabled "Shape Keys" under "Animation" in the export menu.

Unfortunately, this still didn't help my case. Microsoft's 3D Viewer still crashes before I even get to see the file, and I'm getting the same error message in the online viewer.

Does anyone know what's causing this? You can find the .blend file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qFFh5C7p-rlBKaUNro6MNBEi9pMD7B66/view?usp=sharing)!

Comment: The exporter really sucks at this file. Suggest reporting a bug at https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this problem was caused by a Blender modifier. So I had to remove or apply modifiers for shape keys to work